# Why Do I Have No Exit Code From debootstrap?

Tags: bash, debootstrap

I am testing out debootstrap in a chroot via a bash script.

The snippet that runs it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
...
...
sudo debootstrap --verbose --arch=${ARCH} ${RELEASE} ${chroot_dir}
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
  echo "debootstrap failed."
  echo "See ${chroot_dir}/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for more information."
  exit 1
fi

echo "debootstrap succeeded"
```

However, after running the script the last lines printed to the terminal are:

```
I: Chosen extractor for .deb packages: dpkg-deb
I: Extracting adduser...
```

I don't see the failed **or** the succeeded message.

The debootstrap log in the chroot says:

```
tar: ./usr/sbin/addgroup: Cannot create symlink to 'adduser': File exists
tar: ./usr/sbin/delgroup: Cannot create symlink to 'deluser': File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

So clearly something has failed.

Why am I not able to catch this in my error check block?

Comment: Those lines printed to the terminal prefixed with `I:` are the output of debootstrap and I have output part of the debootstrap log in the question too, so yes, I am sure it has started.

Comment: That is interesting. It works as expected. Can you explain in an answer why one works and the other doesn't and what the difference is?

Comment: It was your links that enabled me to search using the right terms for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test for an exit code, `bash` has the following simple syntax:

```bsh
if debootstrap --verbose --arch=${ARCH} ${RELEASE} ${chroot_dir}
then
  echo Success
else
  echo Failure
fi
```

The reason why the other way doesn't work is because `set -e` causes the script to exit *before* the exit code is tested.

For further reading about exit values and error trapping see the following links:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105
- https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/testing-exit-values-bash/